# Alignment issues with layout

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I am trying to put all under ScrollView except footbar buttons which i believe should be firm at the bottom of screen and align the layouts, but somewhere something is going wrong. Any suggestions. Below is the screenshot and code :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E7EBEE"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#0a2436"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" >
            </ImageView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:dividerHeight="1dip"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingTop="0dip"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <!-- android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e7ebee"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingTop="20dip"
                    android:text="SNS Connection"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#737577"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/facebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/list"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="Facebook"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#444444"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/facebook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="15dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ok" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tokentextfacebook"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/list"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="Twitter"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="15dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ok" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tokentexttwitter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/facebook"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Your token is run out. Please reconnect"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Activity"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Support"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Messages"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should avoid using ListView inside a scrollview.

Comment: You can't use a ListView inside a ScrollView.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing
Take a look at @Romain Guy answer.

Comment: Actually you can use ListView inside a ScrollView but the handling of touch events and interceptions can be tricky and must be handled properly to get wanted results of which view scrolls.